# CreateWindow function not working.Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I just starting learning to program, and I just succeed making window.
I'm trying to make a STATIC text area, so I did like this.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    textfield = case WM_CREATE:
        CreateWindow("STATIC", "Hggggg", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER, 
        1, 1, 100, 20, hwnd, 0, 0, 0);

    break;
```

I was watching a youtube video for beginners, and I followed the video. but somehow VisualStudio makes redcurvy-underline under "CreateWindow". I don't really know why. 
Compiling fails, and shows error Number "C2065", "C2664".

This is my whole code

```
#include <Windows.h>

HWND windowHandle;
HWND textfield;


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE prevInstance, PSTR cmdLine, int showCmd)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hIconSm = 0;

    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"rerere";
    wc.lpszMenuName = 0;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);

    //
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    windowHandle = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES, L"rerere", L"rerere",
        (WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX ) | WS_VISIBLE, (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)-300)/2, (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)-300)/2, 300, 300, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);

    //

    if (windowHandle == 0)
        MessageBoxA(0, "creafjeiwa", "ERROR", 0);
    //
    ShowWindow(windowHandle, showCmd);

    //
    UpdateWindow(windowHandle);
    //
    MSG msg; 

    SecureZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(MSG));
    int returnValue = 0;

    while ((returnValue = GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) != 0)
    {
        if (returnValue == -1)
        {
            MessageBoxA(windowHandle, "getmessage fa", "ssss", 0);
            break;
        }

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return(int)msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:

        textfield = CreateWindow("STATIC", "Hggggg", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER, 1, 1, 100, 20, hwnd, 0, 0, 0);
        break;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);

    }
}
```

How can I make Static text area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is in Unicode, you must use Unicode text fields instead of ANSI

```
CreateWindow(L"STATIC", L"Hggggg", ...
```

All text fields need the `L` prefix. If using ANSI, then use ANSI version of API code. You have done that with `MessageBoxA`. But it's more efficient to use Unicode functions throughout with the `L` prefix for text.

Comment: WWOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOWWWWWWWWWWWWW THANK YOU THANKYOU I have been suffering by this for 841 hours. thanks you!

Comment: It's now working sooooooo fine.... here you can see me tear dropping. thank you . programming is so mystery. just putting "L" makes it whole different.